# Subband decomposition using Daubechies filter

Tags: image-processing, wavelet

I have the following two 8-tap filters:

```
h0 ['-0.010597', '0.032883', '0.030841', '-0.187035', '-0.027984', '0.630881', '0.714847', '0.230378']
h1 ['-0.230378', '0.714847', '-0.630881', '-0.027984', '0.187035', '0.030841', '-0.032883', '-0.010597']
```

Here they are on a graph:

[image: graph]

I'm using it to obtain the *approximation* (lower subband of an image).  This is `a(m,n)` in the following diagram:

[image: diagram]

I got the coefficients and diagram from the book [Digital Image Processing, 3rd Edition](http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/DIP-3E/dip3e_main_page.htm), so I trust that they are correct.  The *star* symbol denotes **one dimensional** convolution  (either over rows or over columns).  The down arrow denotes downsampling in **one dimension** (either over rows, or columns).

My problem is that the filter coefficients for `h0` and `h1` sum to greater than 1 (approximately 1.4 or sqrt(2) to be exact).  Naturally, if I convolve any image with the filter, the image will get brighter.  Indeed, here's what I get (expected result on right):

[image: actual] [image: expected]

Can somebody suggest what the problem is here?  **Why should it work** if the convolution filter coefficients sum to greater than 1?

I have the source code, but it's quite long so I'm hoping to avoid posting it here.  If it's absolutely necessary, I'll put it up later.

**EDIT**

What I'm doing is:

1. Decompose into subbands
2. Filter one of the subbands
3. **Recompose** subbands into original image

Note that the point isn't just to have a displayable subband-decomposed image -- I have to be able to perfectly reconstruct the original image from the subbands as well.  So if I scale the filtered image in order to compensate for my decomposition filter making the image brighter, this is what I will have to do:

1. Decompose into subbands
2. **Apply intensity scaling to approximation subband**
3. Filter one of the subbands
4. **Apply inverse intensity scaling to approximation subband**
5. Recompose subbands into original image

Step 2 performs the scaling.  This is what @Benjamin is suggesting.  The problem is that then step 4 becomes necessary, or the original image will not be properly reconstructed.  This longer method **will** work.  However, the textbook explicitly says that **no scaling is performed on the approximation subband**.  Of course, it's possible that the textbook is wrong.  However, what's more possible is I'm misunderstanding something about the way this all works -- this is why I'm asking this question.

**EDIT (2010/7/8)**

I wrote to the author of the book for a confirmation.  He said that you *do* have to perform the scaling, despite of what is being said in the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the sum of the kernel, why not correct the brightness after convolution by dividing by the correct factor?

(For example you can take a 3x3 average with the kernel `[1/9, 1/9, 1/9, 1/9, 1/9, 1/9, 1/9, 1/9, 1/9]`, but also with `[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]` then divide the resulting values by `18`...)

EDIT: As stated in my comment, h1 sums to 0. It appears that h0 and h1 are reversed / inverse of each other, so some of the h0 coefficients may have the wrong sign.

EDIT2: Please read comments. I know this post does not answer the question, I am leaving it here for the comments.

Comment: I've thought of this.  I can normalize the kernel (divide by the sum) before convolution, but I'm a bit surprized this isn't being mentioned anywhere in the book.

Comment: It seems that h0 has the same coefficients as h1, but reversed and inverse. Are the signs of some of the coefficients in h0 reversed? h1 sums to 0 just fine...

Comment: @Benjamin yes, that's *exactly* how it's supposed to be.  h0 is a low-pass filter. h1 is a high pass filter (that's why it sums to zero).  I don't think there is any problem with the signs in h0 -- it's a common filter that gets used fairly often: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2009-March/190484.html.

Comment: @Benjamin I just did a bit more reading.  You can't scale the coefficients (or the output image, which is essentially the same thing) because then the filters will no longer be biorthogonal.  Biorthogonality is described in the book as a necessary condition, which implies scaling **should not** be done.

Comment: @misha: From the wikipedia page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daubechies_wavelet), I see that they CAN be scaled, and are sometimes scaled to sqrt(2) = 1.41, which is the case with your h0.

Comment: @Benjamin: yes, you are correct, the filter **does** sum to sqrt(2).  In fact, if it is anything except sqrt(2), orthogonality/orthonormality will be lost (as the Wikipedia page confirms).  What I meant by "scaling" of the filter in my previous comment was "normalization" of the filter (dividing by its sum).  Sorry for being ambiguous.  The problem still stands: I can't merely "correct the brightness after convolution" as you suggest, because that is equivalent to normalizing the filter, which in turn destroys orthogonality/orthonormality.  Therein lies the problem.

Comment: @misha: This page suggests applying a normalization factor of 1/sqrt(2): http://amath.colorado.edu/courses/5720/2000Spr/Labs/DB/db.html

Comment: @Benjamin thanks for the links.  Try summing their filter -- just like my filter, it adds to sqrt(2).  Their definition for "normalization" is different to what we've been using so far.  We've been talking about `a + b + c + d == 1`.  They're talking about the *norm* of the filter being equal to 1 -- so if the filter is `[ a, b, c, d ]` then `a*a + b*b + c*c + d*d == 1`.  It's two completely different things.

Comment: @Benjamin thanks for your input so far.  I've updated the question to make it more obvious what I'm doing.  Have a look -- hopefully the problem will become clearer.

Comment: @misha: I'm afraid I can't really help... I will leave my answer up as the comments may be helpful to others.

Comment: @Benjamin I contacted the authors.  They've confirmed that you *do* need to scale the image.  Thanks again for your help.